# Printing a TreeSet without brackets and commas

Tags: treeset

**For this project i have to take two separate files and format them into a hash map and print them out.  In order to get the members in order in my treemap i first have to put them into a hash set.  The problem is that when i got to print out the hash map the members names from the tree set are formatted as "[membername, member name]" and i don't know how to get ride of the brackets and commas.  I was thinking about using a for loop but i can't get on to work.  Can someone help?**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab8
{
     public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader membersFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "members.txt" ) );
        BufferedReader pacsFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "pacs.txt" ) );
        TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>> pac2Members = new TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>>();

        while( pacsFile.ready() )
        {
            String pacNames = pacsFile.readLine();
            pac2Members.put(pacNames, new TreeSet<String>());
        }
        pacsFile.close();

        while( membersFile.ready() )
        {
            String[] members = membersFile.readLine().split(" ");
            for( int i=1; i < members.length; i++ )
            {
                pac2Members.get(members[i]).add(members[0]);
            }
        }
        membersFile.close();        

        for( String pacNames : pac2Members.keySet() )
        { 
            System.out.println(pacNames + " " + pac2Members.get(pacNames));
        }

    } // END MAIN

} // CLASS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe the issue here is that "pac2Members.get(pacNames)" in your for loop returns a TreeSet, which is not what you want to print. I'm still not sure why you're using a TreeSet inside your TreeMap. If you're just mapping one "membername" to one "member name", then you should **REALLY** be creating a TreeMap and mapping each "membername" to "member name". If that is what you're trying to do and you don't want to change your code up much, this should work for your 'for' loop:

```
for( String pacNames : pac2Members.keySet() )
{
    System.out.println(pacNames + " " + pac2Members.get(pacNames).first();
}
```

This should only work if the "member name" you want to print is the first element in each TreeSet you map to. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I see that I misread your code. Well, if you have multiple entries in your TreeSet(s), you can try this:

```
    for( String pacNames : pac2Members.keySet() )
    { 
        for (String memberName : pac2Members.get(pacNames)) {
            System.out.println(pacNames + " " + memberName);
        }
    }
```

Not sure if that will work out syntactically, but if you do something along those lines, you should get the result you're looking for.

Comment: there's multiple names for each group that it's mapping too.

Comment: Oh, ok. I misread a piece of your code. I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: that does get rid of the brackets but its printing one pac to one member.  I have to find a way to print one pac and all its members

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like this:

```
public static <T> String toString(Iterable<T> iterable)
{
    if (iterable == null)
    {
        return "null";
    }
    Iterator<T> i = iterable.iterator();
    if (!i.hasNext())
    {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (true)
    {
        T t = i.next();
        sb.append(String.valueOf(t));
        if (!i.hasNext())
        {
            return sb.toString();
        }
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}
```

And call it in your code accordingly:

```
for(String pacNames : pac2Members.keySet())
{ 
    System.out.println(pacNames + " " + toString(pac2Members.get(pacNames)));
}
```

---

> EDIT: That's ridiculous bogus, but that's what was asked for:

```
    for(String pacNames : pac2Members.keySet())
    {
        TreeSet<String> s = pac2Members.get(pacNames);
        Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (;;)
        {
            String t = i.next();
            sb.append(String.valueOf(t));
            if (!i.hasNext())
            {
                break;
            }
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(pacNames + " " + sb.toString());
    }
```

Comment: That works but I'm not allowed to add a method.  I'm supposed to do it in a for loop